# How to hide fields on registration form of Dynamics Portal

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

I need to hide Email on dynamics portal registration form. As highlighted below. I couldn't find any possibility of achieving this. So please help me to hide or at least make the Email disable?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Javascript to hide/disable the Email field, as there is no OOB way to configure/customize their registration/sign form. [This thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/263073/customizing-the-registration-crm-portal-registration-page) and blogger explains about it. It is basically DOM manipulation.

> Create a Content Snippet record (Portal > Content Snippet >New) with
> below details:
>
> Name : Account/Register/PageCopy
>
> Website :
>
> Type : Html
>
> Value: write your own HTML/DOM/JQuery code to add your custom controls
> and perform validations.

From this [community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/219899/customising-register-sign-in-page/589123), you can hide the Azure AD option by following this step:

> for hiding azure you can change a settings under the "Portal Settings"
> entity
>
> Change the record: Authentication/Registration/AzureADLoginEnabled
> value to False